# How can I parse JSON from Azure DevOps work items in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powershell-4.0, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a PS script to get info about work items from the DevOps API. Specifically when I call the work item API there's a property returned called "fields". When I use ConvertFromJson it doesn't seem to be able to parse that property. Is there some way ConvertFromJson can be configured or do I need to do text parsing?

Here's the code:

```
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/H.......s/B....o/_apis/build/builds/$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_DOCMGMT_BUILDID/workitems"

Write-Host "Uri $uri"
Write-Host "AccessToken: $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" } -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json

$itemId = $result.value[0].id
Write-Host $itemId


$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/H.....s/B....o/_apis/wit/workItems/$($itemId)?`$expand=All"

Write-Host "Uri $uri"

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" } -UseBasicParsing | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 5

Write-Host $result
```

Here's the screenshot of the output. Notice the "fields" property is empty?

[image: output from DevOps]

Here's what the same call looks like in Postman

[image: postman screen cap]

Comment: What do you get if you don't use the conversion ?

Comment: For calling APIs, you may find it easier to use Invoke-RestMethod instead. That deals with json results for you automatically, for example.